# Space elevator, maximum force at the bottom

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity

I am looking to find the maximum force the bottom part of the tower must endure.
(Taking down as positive)

The equations of motion for an object with a mass $\lambda\,dr$ experiencing a gravitational force, moving in a circle, is

$$\frac{GM}{r^2} \lambda\,dr + R = \frac{\lambda\,dr\, v^2}{r}$$

Aka, an object under the influence of gravity, experiencing a reaction force from the mass underneath, is equal to the centripetal force.

When that object is moving with the earth's rotation, $v=2\pi r/T_{\rm E}$.

Rearranging I get that

$$\left(-\frac{GM}{r^2} + 
\frac{4\pi^2 r}{T_{\rm E}^2}\right) \lambda\,dr = R$$

Which is the reaction force from the mass below.

Now here's where I need your help, integrating from $R_{\rm E}$ to $R_0$ finds me the sum of all of the reaction forces acting along the elevator. Aka the reaction at the bottom

$$\int_{R_{\rm E}}^{R_{0}} \left(-\frac{GM}{r^2} + \frac{4\pi^2 r}{T_{\rm E}^2}\right)\lambda\,dr$$

I hope this logic is correct.
multiplying this integral by $-1$ should therefore find the total force acting on the bottom (as force is opposite reaction)

$$F = \int_{R_{\rm E}}^{R_0} \left(\frac{GM}{r^2} - \frac{4\pi^2 r}{T_{\rm E}^2}\right) \lambda\,dr.$$

For the special case $T_{E} = \infty$ (aka not rotating)

$$F = \int_{R_{\rm E}}^{R_0} \frac{GM}{r^2}\,\lambda\, dr$$

Which is correct.

Is my logic in that "the sum of the reactions is equal to the reaction at the bottom"  correct? as I can picture it intuitively.

Comment: Yes and no.  Your assumption that $\lambda$ is constant implies that your space elevator is a rope of constant diameter.  **Given that assumption your math is correct**.  But in reality, space elevators undergo a great deal more tension around their centers than at their ends, and in order to have any chance at being strong enough at all, their main structural elements must be tapered from that center-ish point.  This is a freakishly well-developed science, given that no one has done it -- I suggest a web search, and some reading up.